# CSS Media Queries Loading In Wrong Order And Back To Front - Weird

Tags: css, media-queries

so I normally don't have trouble with media queries but I'm integrating forms from click dimensions and styling responsively using media queries. The good news is that the lowest breakpoint media query is loading, the bad is that the others aren't at their respective viewports when I check via dev tools.

I have checked for typos and I'm not seeing anything wrong. Hoping a fresh pair of eyes can highlight the issue.

Also weirdly the browser is picking up the max width before the min width within the breakpoint references. Never seen this before.

```
/*--- PIXEL 2 ---*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 411px) {
  .clickdform input[type='text'],
  .clickdform textarea,
  .clickdform select{
      min-width:350px!important;
   }
}


/*--- IPHONE X -6-7-8 STYLE ---*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 375px) {
  .clickdform input[type='text'],
  .clickdform textarea,
  .clickdform select{
      min-width:312px!important;
   }
}

/*--- Galaxy S5 ---*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 360px) {
  .clickdform input[type='text'],
  .clickdform textarea,
  .clickdform select{
      min-width:300px!important;
   }
} 

/*--- IPHONE 5 - SE ---*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .clickdform input[type='text'],
  .clickdform textarea,
  .clickdform select{
      min-width:259px!important;
   }
}
```

Comment: _“the browser is picking up the max width before the min width within the breakpoint references”_ - no clue what this is even supposed to mean. // Do you have the rest of the page properly “set up” for responsiveness, specifically viewport meta tag? Please provide a [mcve] of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `min-width` in your CSS is not necessary.

If you want to target on an actual device screen width, try to use `max-device-width`

```css
/*--- PIXEL 2 ---*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 411px) {
  .clickdform input[type='text'],
  .clickdform textarea,
  .clickdform select{
      min-width:350px!important;
   }
}


/*--- IPHONE X -6-7-8 STYLE ---*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .clickdform input[type='text'],
  .clickdform textarea,
  .clickdform select{
      min-width:312px!important;
   }
}

/*--- Galaxy S5 ---*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .clickdform input[type='text'],
  .clickdform textarea,
  .clickdform select{
      min-width:300px!important;
   }
} 

/*--- IPHONE 5 - SE ---*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .clickdform input[type='text'],
  .clickdform textarea,
  .clickdform select{
      min-width:259px!important;
   }
}
```

Comment: It's funny you say this, I also tried this approach initially but it had no effect on the output. Which is why I tried to be more specific. Usually this approach works.

Comment: Also if i use max-device-width this doesn't actually work. Unless I also add the aspect ratio and viewport orientation also. But I still have the same issue lol.

Comment: That's weird. If you can provide a HTML markup, it would be more helpful to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

About “the browser is picking up the max width before the min width within the breakpoint references” 
make sure that your browser window is not zoomed (you can use Control/Command + 0 to reset zoom settings and return to standard 100% zoom).

Comment: I also tried this, but wasn't sure how this would affect the css. Still reads like below for example: @media only screen and (max-width: 360px) and (min-width: 321px)